# Add Product then error show in magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have click add to cart product then get the error:

Cannot read contents from file :

> "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/D:/xampp/tmp/phpC9A.tmp" Warning !file_get_contents(C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/D:/xampp/tmp/phpC9A.tmp): failed to open stream: Invalid argument